# Initialize and Declare ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>> Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

How can I both initialize and declare an ArrayList<ArrayList> in Kotlin.
The problem I am currently having is I have a set of data for this particular ArrayList, and am curious on how to return this set of data in one line.
For example

```
fun returnArray(): ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>> {
       return /* ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>> with pre determined data */
}
```

Comment: How do the *pre determined data* look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun returnArray(): ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>> =
    arrayListOf(arrayListOf(1, 2, 3), arrayListOf(4, 5, 6))
```

you can use `arrayListOf` to declare and populate your list